# How to create a user with a verified email address in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

In my server fixture, I'm populating the database with some test users using the `Accounts.createUser` function. Now, I'm trying to figure out how to flag the email of the created user as verified.

I've tried to set the `verified` flag directly but it doesn't work:

```
Meteor.users.findOne(userId).emails[0].verified = true
```

Comment: you should run a meteor.users.update({user, $set{"emails.verified" : true}};

Comment: of course! why haven't I thought of it. do you want to add your comment as an answer so I can officially acknowledge it? The exact syntax is: `Meteor.users.update(joeId, { $set: { ""emails.0.verified": true }});`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to update your user and set the verified flag to true. Try this.

```
Meteor.users.update(userId, {$set: {"emails.0.verified" :true}});
```

This will update the first email in the `emails: []` array.

Comment: There is a small typo in the answer's code. It should be `emails.0.verified` instead of `email.0.verified`.

Comment: Where do you retrieve the userId of your default created user?  Do you set their _id manually?  Or can you user their username?

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle, userid returned after successfull registration from function `Accounts.createUser`, ex. `var newUserId = Accounts.createUser(...)`